# Error Using property Wrapper in class swift 5.1

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5, combine

I am using UserDefaults and Combine in SwiftUI.

**My UserDefault.swift file:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct UserDefault<T> {
    let key: String
    let defaultValue:T

    var wrappedValue:T {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? T ?? defaultValue
        } set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

When using this struct in the following class as follows:

**DataStore.swift file:**

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

final class DataStore : ObservableObject { //(1)
    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<DataStore, Never>()

    @UserDefault(key: "firstLaunch", defaultValue: true) //(2)
    var firstLaunch:Bool{
        didSet{
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I am getting 2 errors:

**(1):Class 'DataStore' has no initializers**

**(2):Generic struct 'UserDefault' cannot be used as an attribute**

I think there is a change or depreciation in swift 5.1, but I am unable to find it.

Comment: Did you mark your struct with `@propertyWrapper` or just forgot to include in your snippet above?

Comment: Oops, my bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct UserDefault<T> {
    let key: String
    let defaultValue: T

    init(key: String, defaultValue: T) {
        self.key = key
        self.defaultValue = defaultValue
    }

    var wrappedValue: T {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? T ?? defaultValue
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `@propertyWrapper` annotation to your `UserDefault` struct.

```
@propertyWrapper
struct UserDefault<T> {
...
```